# AJAX GET request not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, get

I am trying to make an AJAX call, it's the very first time I use AJAX, my code is the following:

```
$.get( "validate.php", { 'userinput':'x'}, function(response) {
    if( response.status ) alert( "Matches found" );
    else alert( "No matches" );
});
```

vaidate.php:

```
<?php
$user_input=$_GET['userinput'];
//print_r($user_input);
if(!is_null($user_input)) exit( '{ "status": true }' );
else exit( '{ "status": false }' );
?>
```

If I access my validate.php, I get "undefined index" error. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: well, for one, `print_r($user_input);` needs to be commented out for jQuery to parse the return properly, but you first need to fix the undefined index error

Comment: Syntax is a bit off - you dont need the last `}`

Comment: yeah, it was commented in the code, sorry. that was only when I tested it out

Comment: You should also use getJSON since your php is returning JSON. As far as undefined index, i don't know why you are getting that, unless you didn't pass ?userinput=x when you tried it directly.

Comment: @KevinB I would be really grateful if you could give me a link or any details

Comment: @karthikr it was inside a function, I copied the closing bracket by mistake. thanks

Comment: Do you mean access, as in opening validate.php in a browser. In that case, yes, that would give you an undefined index error.

Answer (score 1):

The php looks fine once you comment out the test code:

```
<?php
  $user_input=$_GET['userinput'];
  //print_r($user_input);
  if(!is_null($user_input)) exit( '{ "status": true }' );
  else exit( '{ "status": false }' );
?>
```

you need to specify that you expect JSON, the simplest way would be to use getJSON

```
$.getJSON( "validate.php", { 'userinput':'x'}, function(response) {
    if( response.status ) alert( "Matches found" );
    else alert( "No matches" );
});
```

Other alternative with jQuery is

```
$.get( "validate.php", { 'userinput':'x'}, function(response) {
    if( response.status ) alert( "Matches found" );
    else alert( "No matches" );
},"json");
```

or to set the contentType header in php:

```
<?php
  $user_input=$_GET['userinput'];
  //print_r($user_input);
  header('Content-type: application/json');
  if(!is_null($user_input)) exit( '{ "status": true }' );
  else exit( '{ "status": false }' );
?>
```

Comment: The other options are to pass "json" as the 4th parameter to `$.get()`, or set the `Content-Type` of the response to be "application/json". Although I agree this is the best setup

Comment: @itachi performance-wise maybe, but it's much simpler to use a shortcut if you don't need to change any of the default options, and if performance is an issue, `$.ajax` vs `$.get` isn't going to be your bottleneck.

Comment: @KevinB Performance wise chosing will be micro optimisation which is root of every evil. i say it is better because `ajax()` gives you more control of the flow.

Comment: Right, but what if you don't need more control? My point is it doesn't matter. One isn't "better" than the other, they each have their place.